# How to run gui based programs on macbook by terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, graphics, gpu

I am on **mac os**  and have *terminal* in it. I run simple c++ programs on terminal by command **g++**  but i don't know how to run gpu based c++ programs like code containing *graphics.h* file

And pls suggest how to download all c++ libs and c++ in mac without xcode (because it is of 5.5gb)

Is it possible...

Comment: gpu or gui ? those are quite different things

Comment: You don't **run** a program with g++.

Comment: _all c++ libs and c++_ what is **all**? See [command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/features/).

Answer (score 1):

macOS has au unusual way of producing executables called app bundles. (Historically this is to reproduce on the HSFS file system what was part of the old OS 9 filesystem which associated attribute data to files).

[Here](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/) is a link explaining how to launch an executable from a terminal. In short, use

> open -a ApplicationName

Comment: When answering questions you should put a summary of any link you post so that should the link go stale the information doesn't.

Comment: Post has been updated.